# T-sql Monday before date

Tags: t-sql

I work at a college and our student management systems academic year start date is determined by the Monday on or before the 1st of August. I need to match this in my query, is there a way to easily get the date of the Monday on or before this date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set datefirst 1; -- Make Monday the first day of the week

select dateadd(dd, -1*(datepart(dw, '2009-08-01')-1), '2009-08-01')
```

Returns July 27th, 2009, which is the Monday on or before August 1. Change it to 2005 when Aug 1 was a Monday and the query will return 08-01

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because I needed both a Sunday week and a Monday week in the same query.  This works across different "datefirst" settings:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, -((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '20110515') - DATEPART(dw, '19000101') + 7) % 7), '20110515')
```

"DATEPART(dw, '19000101')" will determine your "datefirst" setting since 1900-01-01 was on a Monday.  If you want a Tuesday based week, you can change 19000101 to 19000102.

BTW, '20110515' is the only date format that works across all SQL Server culture settings. Dates like '2011-05-06' will get mis-interpreted in certain countries. (credit to Itzik Ben-Gan for pointing this out)

Answer (score 1):

You could use datepart to get the weekday, and then do a little math to back into your monday.  This example is using the US default of datefirst 7 (in which Monday is day 2 of the week).  Adjust the days to add to be which day of the week Monday is for your locale.

```
select dateadd(dd, -datepart(dw, '2009-08-01') + 2, '2009-08-01')
```

Comment: I marked this down since the following returns an incorrect result: select dateadd(dd, -datepart(dw, '2011-05-15') + 2, '2011-05-15').  This returns '2011-05-16'.

Answer (score 0):

very hacky

```
DECLARE @weekday int

SELECT @weekday = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '1-Aug-2009')

SELECT CASE
 WHEN @weekday = 1 THEN '1-Aug-2009' ELSE DATEADD ( dd,(@weekday-2)*-1, '1-Aug-2009') 
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic algorithm that will return the first Monday of any month (@inputdate):

```
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, dateadd(dd, 6 - datepart(day, @inputDate), @inputDate)), 0)
```

It is a common method for getting the first monday of the month in SQL Server. This [link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3076421/Examples-of-how-to-Calculate-Different-SQL-Server-Dates.htm) explains how the above calculation works along with many other date calculations.

**Here is how the above algorithm could be used to get the Monday on or before the 1st day of a month:**

```
-- Set month to get Monday before or at 1st of month.
DECLARE @inputDate DATETIME
SET @inputDate = '2009-08-01'

-- Get first Monday of month.
DECLARE @firstMonday DATETIME
SET @firstMonday = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, dateadd(dd, 6 - datepart(day, @inputDate), @inputDate)), 0)

-- Determine date for first Monday on or before 1st of month.
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = @firstMonday
IF @firstMonday > @inputDate
    SET @startDate = DATEADD(wk, -1, @firstMonday)

SELECT @startDate
```